# Is it possible to add locations dinamically on ngninx reverse proxy docker?

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

### Infrastructure

I want to create a docker with the following structure:
[image: Structure]
I intend to have a `docker-compose` that inside has 3 main images (a database, an api on port 8080 and a frontend on port 443). Besides that I have a couple of extra docker-compose that represent other services.

### Functionality

The feature i'm looking for is being able to create container instances of the secundary docker-compose files from inside the nginx reverse proxy(main docker-compose) and map that port to an unique subdirectory (it's important to be able of creating multiple instances of the same docker-compose).

### What I found

To acomplish the rest of the features already found some resources:

- [Create a nginx reverse `docker-compose`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxngRDmHTM0&t=662s)
- [Share a volume among the API and nginx to update the configuration file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-docker-containers)
- [Run container from inside container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973941/docker-run-container-from-inside-container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem using traefik, it allows me to add routes by the subdirectory to containers without modifying the build configuration.

The `docker-compose.yml` would be something like this:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.2.0
    ports:
      - "${FRONT_HTTP_PORT:-80}:80"
      - "${TRAEFIK_PORT:-8080}:8080"
    environment: 
      - TRAEFIK_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_DOCKER_EXPOSEDBYDEFAULT=false
      - TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_DOCKER=true
      - TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_DOCKER_NETWORK=traefik01
      - TRAEFIK_API_INSECURE=true
      - TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_FRONT=true
      - TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_FRONT_ADDRESS=:${FRONT_HTTP_PORT:-80}
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    security_opt:
      - label:type:docker_t

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    expose:
      - 80
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=front"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=PathPrefix(`/frontend{regex:$$|/.*}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.middlewares=frontend-stripprefix"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.frontend-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/frontend"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.priority=2"
      # - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.priority=1"
      # - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:ctf.itasahobby.com"
    stdin_open: true

  api:
    build: ./api
    expose: 
      - 80
    links:
      - database
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=front"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=PathPrefix(`/api{regex:$$|/.*}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=api-stripprefix"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.api-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/api"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.priority=2"

  database:
    build: ./database
    restart: always
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: testnetwork
```

Then to add a new container it has to contain the same network interface and the labels in order to set the routes, for instance:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  app2:
    image: httpd:2.4.41-alpine
    expose:
      - 80
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app2.entrypoints=front"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app2.rule=PathPrefix(`/app2{regex:$$|/.*}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app2.middlewares=app2-stripprefix"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.app2-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/app2"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: testnetwork
```